# How can I switch on the highlighting of the current symbol in IntelliJ?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

When navigating the code in IntelliJ, when the cursor is on a given variable name (for instance), I would like the IDE to highlight all the other usages of this variable in the given file (I think this is the default behaviour in Eclipse). How can I switch it on?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3763183/intellij-how-to-auto-highlight-variables-like-in-eclipse

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Settings" -> "IDE Settings" -> "Editor" -> "Highlight usages of element at caret"